# How to get my text in the middle of my div

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I can't move my text to the middle of my div. I have `text-align: center;` and `justify-content: center;` but it still stays at the top of my div, and won't move unless I force it to where I want it to go.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.top-nav {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  color: white;
}

.big-hero {
  background-image: url(../images/books.webp);
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: -22px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <NAV class="top-nav">
    <UL>
      <LI>Home</LI>
      <LI>About</LI>
      <LI>Gallery</LI>
      <LI>Calendar</LI>
      <LI>Contact</LI>
    </UL>
  </NAV>

  <div class="big-hero">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: `justify-content: center` won't have any affect unless the display of the element is a `flex` or `grid`. So, you also need to set `display: flex` on `.big-hero`.

Comment: *About US* is indeed in the middle, `text-align:center` works fine here ,white on white ... not easy to see the text  ....

Answer (score 1):

you have to use display:flex for the justify-content: center to work

try writing

```
.big-hero{
    background-image: url(../images/books.webp);
    height: 100vh;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: -22px;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;        /* add this*/
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: text-align alone worked already itself , i don't understand why the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `justify-content: left;` to center.

```css
.top-nav{
    background-color: gray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
}

.top-nav{
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

 ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.big-hero {
  background-image: url(../images/books.webp);
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: -22px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<NAV class="top-nav">
    <UL>
        <LI>Home</LI>
        <LI>About</LI>
        <LI>Gallery</LI>
        <LI>Calendar</LI>
        <LI>Contact</LI>
    </UL>
</NAV>

<div class="big-hero">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%;` to your `ul` then simply add `text-align: center;` to your `li`'s.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.top-nav {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.big-hero {
  background-image: url(../images/books.webp);
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: -22px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
    <li>Calendar</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="big-hero">
  <h1>About Us</h1>
</div>
```